# Insertar y Concatenar Texto en un archivo en C++

Tags: c++, archivo

Quiero insertar múltiples líneas en un archivo .txt y leer todo el archivo .txt para validar las inserciones, el problema es que siempre me muestra solo una línea.
La inserción de texto la hago en una función y la mando a llamar muchas veces.

Esta es mi función para insertar texto:

```
int escribirEnArchivo(string texto)
{
    char in[20 + 1] = {0};
    char out[80 + 1] = {0};
    char str[400] = {0};
    FILE *file;

    memset(in, 0, sizeof(in));
    memset(out, 0, sizeof(out));
    memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));

    strcpy(in, texto.c_str());

    file = fopen("Prueba.txt", "a");
    fputs((char*)in, file);
    fclose(file);

    file = fopen("Prueba.txt", "r");
    fgets(out, 80, (FILE*)file);
    fclose(file);

    cout<<out<<endl;

    return 1;
}
```

Siempre se imprime solo: `1|Hola Mundo!|25.00|true`

Esta función manda a llamar la inserción varias veces:

```
int foo()
{
    escribirEnArchivo("1|Hola Mundo!|20.00|true");
    escribirEnArchivo("2|Adios Mundo!|50.00|false");
    escribirEnArchivo("3|Hola Mundo!|75.00|true");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu codigo utilizas muchas funciones de C clasico orientado a arrays terminados en '\0', como `strcpy()`, `fputs()` y `fgets()`. Sin embargo, en C++ puedes usar los objetos tipo "streams" que encapsula la necesidad de usar write, read, calcular y mantener el tamaño de tus buffers como en `in[20+1]; out[40+1]`, sospecho que al mantener un tamaño fijo de 21 y 41 bytes solo alcanzas a  leer la primera linea.

Al reescribir tu codigo utilizando stream vemos que es mucho mas simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int escribirEnArchivo(string texto)
{
    ofstream out_file;  // Output File Stream para escribir (writing)
    ifstream in_file;   // Input File Stream  para leer (reading)

    // Escribir el archivo
    out_file.open("Prueba.txt", ios::app); // ios::app es lo paralello a "a" que significa append agregar al final del archivo
    out_file << texto << endl; // agregamos al buffer del stream
    out_file.close();  // flush el buffer y cerramos. flush el buffer basicamente hace write en el archivo.

    // Leer el archivo
    in_file.open("Prueba.txt");
    cout << "[Prueba.txt]  >>>" << endl;
    cout << in_file.rdbuf(); //endl funciona como activador de flush()
    // in_file.close() es llamado automaticamente en el destructor de in_file
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    escribirEnArchivo("1|Hola Mundo!|20.00|true");
    escribirEnArchivo("2|Adios Mundo!|50.00|false");
    escribirEnArchivo("3|Hola Mundo!|75.00|true");
}
```