# Concatenar archivos en c++

Tags: c++

He estado intentando hacer un programa en C++ del siguiente enunciado, en teoría luego debemos compilar y ejecutar en una consola de Linux pero no logro que funcione:

> Construye un subprograma que dados dos ficheros de texto cuyos datos
> sean enteros añada, al final del primer fichero, todos los elementos
> del segundo fichero.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

#include<fstream>

#include<assert.h>

using namespace std;

void concatenarFicheros (char nombref1[], char nombref2[]);

int main(int argc, char* argv[2])
{
    assert(argc==2);
    concatenarFicheros(argv[1],argv[2]);
    return 0;
}

void concatenarFicheros (char nombref1[], char nombref2[])
{
    ifstream f1;

    ofstream f2;

    int n;

    f1.open(nombref1, ios::out|ios::app);

    f2.open(nombref2, ios::in);

    if (f1)
    {
        while (!f1.eof())  //mientras no hayas llegado al final del fichero
        {
            f1>>n;
            f2 << n << endl;
        }
    }
    f1.close();
    f2.close();
}
```

Comment: Te servirían alguno de estos enlaces para responder a tu pregunta?:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/202089/insertar-y-concatenar-texto-en-un-archivo-en-c
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/250708/concatenar-archivos-txt-recibidos-desde-el-terminal-y-pasados-a-una-funci%c3%b3n-usan

Comment: Hola! Qué sucede cuando usas este código? Algún mensaje de error? Qué resultado obtienes y por qué es diferente del esperado?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner cómo lo compilas, cómo lo ejecutas, y qué es lo que obtienes, y como es diferente del esperado?

Comment: "Eso es lo que has intentado" pero ¿qué problemas has encontrado? ¿qué resultado obtienes y qué resultado esperabas obtener?

Comment: Debe dar error porque concatenarFicheros(argv[1],argv[2]); no va a andar, los arrays son basados en cero y debería ser concatenarFicheros(argv[0],argv[1]);

Comment: @CarlosE.Ferro `argv[0]` es **el nombre del programa**. Los parámetros de verdad empiezan en `argv[1]`

Comment: Ooops. Perdón, @eferion, comenté demasiado rápido y tienes razón.

Answer (score 1):

> Construye un subprograma que dados dos ficheros de texto cuyos datos sean enteros añada, al final del primer fichero, todos los elementos del segundo fichero.

Empezamos mal. Lo que intenta tu código es leer números del primer archivo y añadirlos al final del segundo. Es justo lo contrario a lo que te están pidiendo:

```
while (!f1.eof())
{
    f1 >> n;         // Lees de f1
    f2 << n << endl; // Guardas en f2
}
```

Aparte de eso, para poder concatenar, necesitas abrir el archivo en modo edición y posicionar el cursor **al final** del archivo. Si revisas la documentación de [`fstream`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/):

| member constant | stands for | access |
| --- | --- | --- |
| in | input | File open for reading: the internal stream buffer supports input operations. |
| out | output | File open for writing: the internal stream buffer supports output operations. |
| binary | binary | Operations are performed in binary mode rather than text. |
| ate | at end | The output position starts at the end of the file. |
| app | append | All output operations happen at the end of the file, appending to its existing contents. |
| trunc | truncate | Any contents that existed in the file before it is open are discarded. |

Verás que está el valor `ate` que sirve justamente para eso.

Recapitulando. Lo primero que tienes que hacer es abrir `f1` en **modo escritura**  y posicionar el cursor al final del archivo. `f2` se abre en modo lectura

```
std::ofstream f1;
f1.open(nombref1, ios::out|ios::ate);

std::ifstream f2;
f2.open(nombref2);
```

No estaría más, llegados a este punto, comprobar que se han podido abrir **ambos** archivos

```
if (f1.is_open() && f2.is_open())
{
  // ...
}
```

Y ahora ya si se pueden copiar los datos de un archivo a otro

```
int n;
f2 >> n;
while( !f2.eof() )
{
    f1 << n << '\n';
    f2 >> n;
}
```

Si te estás preguntando por qué razón estoy leyendo el primer valor fuera del bucle entonces debes saber que el flag `EOF` únicamente se activa **tras la primera lectura incorrecta**. Es decir, si un archivo tiene 4 números, el flag se activará cuando se intente leer un quinto valor.

Tu bucle:

```
while (!f1.eof())  //mientras no hayas llegado al final del fichero
{
    f1>>n;
    f2 << n << endl;
}
```

Tiene un problema, y es que, en caso de funcionar, para un archivo de 4 números ... escribirá 5. Al llegar al final del archivo y hacer `f1 >> n` únicamente se activará el flag EOF (no se leerán números porque ya no quedan), después se almacenará en `f2` el valor almacenado en `n` (valor fantasma) y entonces, ya si, compruebas si está activo el flago `EOF`

Answer (score 0):

Abres los archivos de origen y el archivo de destino y copias los datos consecutivamente:

```
void concatena(const std::string &A, const std::string &B, const std::string &destino)
{
    std::ifstream a{A}, b{B};
    std::ofstream resultado{destino};

    using iiterator = std::istream_iterator<char>;
    using oiterator = std::ostream_iterator<char>;

    if (a && b && resultado)
    {
        std::copy(iiterator{a}, iiterator{}, oiterator{resultado});
        std::copy(iiterator{b}, iiterator{}, oiterator{resultado});
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLLasMwEEXX1lcMLiQ2pIu@29g1JOt@gqCMZSUVJKNgy4Ui9O2u/AxpEuhGSDP3aK6uLQ6HW7FD2jbNjSKxqwsJqdKVKSXuM3asbc5LysgSjS4zxr61KkBoEmgkYeR3lYHKFMulxxRtYbZawIXq@mK1kJVRpGNmWdA11DAd0K7cAnK7dsnQ0mOrlFW9M1hoO@BewoK6am9Uo1V47yepHvoc66n4wjJLRr3@q9dX9CxQG4gQZjPI22UyEbPAm@8tCn34iSYLFv0Ljid/mKbZCXdxcoXO/0s75hhTZGCPiqIuy9braWhoQwzdYBYhTSG843TP6YHTI6cnTmF31QU0t2E@oXmHPnN64fTK6W3kWHD8KfykBXjGLyKMu@y8O6r3stRevPFpR6dfW1ivdAkIyLJRCKfJ1qab/CFVoZcQtode2O7mnOZ9Ek3zCw)</kbd>.